# Get latest Git tag from a repository using Phing

Tags: git, build, phing

I'm new to phing and building a script to automate some build tasks.

Is there a way to retrieve just the most recently added tag to a git repo? I can pull up a list of all my tags but cannot seem to filter it down to the latest one.

Here's the relevant code that fetches my git tags:

```
    <gittag 
        repository="${repo.dir.resolved}" 
        list="true" 
        outputProperty="versionTag" 
        pattern="v*" />
```

The output of the above results in a list of tags (prefixed by "v"):

```
[gittag] git-tag output: v1.0.0
v1.0.1
v1.0.2
```

Any ideas on how I can get this down to just the **v1.0.2**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to get this done as follows:

```
    <exec 
        outputProperty="latestVersion" 
        command="git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`" 
        dir="${repo.dir.resolved}"/>
```

It does work, though I'm open to suggestions if this can be improved!

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well.

Comment: The only suggestion I would have is to extend the GitTag task and submit the changes for inclusion.

Comment: Thannks @Travis - I will look into it!